# How to show cylinder $S^1 \times [1,2]$ is homeomorphic to an annulus?

Tags: general-topology

The annulus is $\{x\in \mathbb{R}^2 \mid 1\leq |x| \leq 2\}$
I am unfamiliar with finding homeomorphisms, can someone get me started?

Comment: You might try mapping the boundary of the annulus to the edges (the circles) of the cylinder. Then use those as guides for the remainder of the surface.

Answer (score 2):

For $p=(\cos A,\sin A) \in S^1$ and $x \in [1,2]$, let $f((p,x))=(x \cos A,x \sin A)$.

Answer (score 1):

Can you picture how to "flatten out" the cylinder to become an annulus? If not, think about pulling apart one of those [ketchup cups](http://cdn.foodbeast.com.s3.amazonaws.com/content/wp-content/uploads/2012/08/ketchup-wrong.jpg).

Now describe this map more precisely: where does the top circle go? Where does the bottom circle go? From there, everything in between should work itself out.